# Several arguments in if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that relies on argparse. The mainbody of the script has if statements like this:

```
if results.short == True and results.verbose == False and results.verbose2 == False and results.list == False and results.true == False:
```

Isn't there any shorter way to do that? Say I have more than those 5 arguments, typing each of them in every statement seems like repetitive work.

Can't if do something like:

```
if results.short == True and "results.%s"== False % (everyotherresults.something):
```

I'm writing for Python 2.7

Comment: You can use just `if results.short and not "results.%s" % (something)`. But if it's cumbersome you can put all your cases in a dictionary and iterate through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you shouldn't compare to `bool` in boolean expressions, eg:

```
if (results.short 
    and not results.verbose 
    and not results.verbose2 
    and not results.list 
    and not results.true):
```

Comment: Even shorter like this `if results.short and not (results.verbose and results.verbose2 and results.list and results.true)`

Comment: er... no; extracting the not would be: `result.short and not (result.verbose or ...)` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 4):

You can use `any` function on list, and move all your arguments from 2nd in a list: -

```
if results.short and \
   not any([results.verbose, results.verbose2, results.list, results.true]):
```

`any` function returns `True` if at least one value in the list is `True`. So, just use `not any`, which will return `True` if all the values in the list is `False`.

And yes, you don't need to compare boolean value with `True` or `False`.

Comment: @Marcin. Ah! sorry. Just a copy paste problem.

Comment: maybe better yet: `if results.short == True and not any([item for item in results]):`

Comment: @EyalAr.. Still we would need to create that list. And not all values in `results` should be `False`.

Comment: @EyalAr -- that will never return True, since it requires `results.short` to be both True (in the first clause) and false (in the second clause).

Comment: these are not semantically identical.  One reason to use `foo.bar and foo.baz` is because `foo.baz` raises an exception when `foo.bar` is False.  Gathering the results into a list that won't be used for anything is also wasteful.

Comment: @SamMussmann, RohitJain, you are right, I didn't pay attention.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy but this won't check the truth-value of `results.verbose` if `results.short` is True.  Where do you see the semantic inequivalence?  Also, I think creating the list is part of the overhead of using a scripting language. :-)

Comment: The difference is that `getattr(results, 'verbose2')` is executed *before* `bool(results.vebose) is False`